# How to get the return type of a generic function inside a class with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

With Angular's typed forms, I want to get the return type (R) of `FormBuilder.group<T>()` such that I can use this R like this: `FormGroup<R>`.

For this I tried:

```
type R = ReturnType<FormBuilder['group']<T>>;
```

Which is invalid Typescript.

Is there a way to get R to be the return type of the group function for a specific generic parameter T?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do this (maybe it's an oversight?) without dropping to the expression level first:

```
declare const _group: FormBuilder["group"];
type R = ReturnType<typeof _group<{ foo: "bar" }>>; // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgMWiAQgV2AGwCYCmUcAvnAGZQQhwBEAAgIYB2A5pjo1APTloDOtANwBYAFDjCAY05QCcKRGb94AfVZVMYAFwo0WXISgBtWhohbaAXVFiYATzDyASnAC8cZwRiYozACqOBAA8Dk4Q5HDqmmDBSHwQurQARly0pAB8GbZAA)